# How to hide a woocommerce setting tab from admin & shop manager?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to hide specific tabs in woocommerce setting. I read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36779307/hide-a-woocommerce-setting-tab

It worked for shop manager only.

1. I want to hide it for adminstrator too. I tried to add similar snippet by replacing shop manager with adminstrator, but got error.
2. In my website there ar multiple administratior. Is it possible to hide it for specific admin user?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide for specific users, just change the if statement. eg

```
if( in_array( $user->ID, [LIST_OF_USER_IDS] ) ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working properly.